# Apple music won't open. High Memory usage

Tags: memory, apple-music

[image]

Apple music does not open. Is there a way I can 'reinstall' or fix it? The memory usage jumps too high.

I am left with no option but to force quit it

Comment: Can you boot in Safe mode (push shift key at boot) and retry in this mode? If ok reboot the Mac and retry.